# PHP MySQLi Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Sorry to seem like a noob with this but i've got a query that i've wrote and it doesn't seem to be working and i've made sure all those variables are valid. There are no errors, no nothing. It's a form action. I've checked the query, re-wrote it and also copied/pasted a query from another page in there; still no luck! Have I made a stupid mistake somewhere?

Form:

```
<div class="container">
<?php
 if($_SESSION['submit_success']){
echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Done! </strong>Your form has been submitted. Please wait up to a week for a reply. Good luck!
</div>';
  } elseif($_SESSION['submit_error']){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Error! </strong>You have already sent an application.
</div>';
  }
?>
  <div class="well">
    <center><legend>Sponsorship form</legend></center>
      <form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="submitsponsorship.php">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label r_110">Your details</label><br>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control r_90" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your full name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control r_90" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your email address" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" name="ign" class="form-control r_90" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your in-game name (Minecraft username)" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="number" name="age" class="form-control r_90" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your age" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control r_90" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your country" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><label class="control-label r_90">Server details</label><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="name" name="size" class="form-control r_90" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What size server are you looking for?" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select class="form-control r_90" name="serverlocation" required>
                    <option value="">Choose a server location</option>
                    <option value="europe">Europe (France)</option>
                    <option value="usa">USA</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><label class="control-label r_90">Convince us!</label><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control r_90" rows="3" name="why-requesting" placeholder="Why are you requesting sponsorship?" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control r_90" rows="3" name="why-shouldwe" placeholder="Why should we provide you with sponsorship and not someone else?" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control r_90" rows="3" name="how-promote" placeholder="How do you intend on promoting Swift?" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <label class="control-label r_90"><small><i>(optional)</i></small></label>
                <textarea class="form-control r_90" rows="3" name="social-links" placeholder="Links to YouTube Channel / Website etc."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="r_500">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Apply">
            </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
    <small>Please note that by clicking <i>Apply</i>, you agree to advertising for ******* in the way stated above, <i>if</i> provided with a server.</small>
  </div>
</div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['submit_success']) ?>
```

This is `submitsponsorship.php`:

```
    <?php
include 'overall.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'resources/database.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$check = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM sponsorships WHERE email = '". $email ."'");
var_dump($check);

if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){
  $_SESSION['submit_error'] = 1;
  header('Location: /sponsorships');
} else {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $status = 0;
  $ign = $_POST['ign'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  $serverlocation = $_POST['serverlocation'];
  $why_requesting = $_POST['why-requesting'];
  $why_shouldwe = $_POST['why-shouldwe'];
  $how_promote = $_POST['how-promote'];
  $social_links = $_POST['social-links'];
  $applyquery = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `sponsorships` (`status`, `name`, `email`, `ign`, `age`, `country`, `size`, `serverlocation`, `why-requesting`, `why-shouldwe`, `how-promote`, `social-links`) VALUES (".$status.",".$name.",".$email.",".$ign.",".$age.",".$country.",".$size.",".$serverlocation.",".$why_requesting.",".$why_shouldwe.",".$how_promote.",".$social_links.")");
  //$_SESSION['submit_success'] = 1;
  //header("Location: /sponsorships");
  echo "success";
} ?>
```

And yes, it does print out "success" but does not enter anything to the database. I'm sorry in advance if it's something stupid.

Maybe you want to check the database connection? (Works fine for every other query in my project)
Here it is;

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","swiftsetups");

// Check connection //

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "MySQL Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>
```

Comment: ` or die(mysqli_error())` after your query would be a good start. Also, use parameterised queries!!!

Comment: Unqoted (and unescaped) string literals. Ask `mysqli_error()`. It's best fixed with using prepared statements.

Comment: Wrong type of quoting action. Good => `'". YYY ."'` etc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - these are `". XXX ."` <= Yours-Bad.

Comment: Why not check error? : 


mysqli_query("..") or exit(mysqli_error());

Comment: This is a beautiful example for "How to use mysqli wrong".
Don't put input values into an SQL query with string concatenation.
Use prepared statements!

Comment: Knew I should have looked into MySQLi more before using it, got it working, thanks guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
$applyquery = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `sponsorships` (`status`, `name`, `email`, `ign`, `age`, `country`, `size`, `serverlocation`, `why-requesting`, `why-shouldwe`, `how-promote`, `social-links`) VALUES (".$status.",".$name.",".$email.",".$ign.",".$age.",".$country.",".$size.",".$serverlocation.",".$why_requesting.",".$why_shouldwe.",".$how_promote.",".$social_links.")");
```

to this:

```
$applyquery = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO sponsorships (status, name, email, ign, age, country, size, serverlocation, why-requesting, why-shouldwe, how-promote, social-links) VALUES ('$status','$name','$email','$ign','$age','$country','$size','$serverlocation','$why_requesting','$why_shouldwe','$how_promote','$social_links')");
```

in my experience, `mysqli_query` dont act like an `echo()` function in which you would concat things using `". $var ."`

EDIT
However after looking through the comments, it seems that
`'".$var."'` is acceptable?

Comment: Yep, got it working using those comments, thank for the aid nevertheless!

Comment: You may also want to thing about protecting your `$_POST['']` from possible malicious entries? http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php